# Unable to change field type to not null with default value

Tags: postgresql

I have a simple SQL statement, which looks like so:

```
alter table my_table alter column my_field set data type numeric(12,4) not null default 0;
```

But I get an error message, that points to `not`. What is wrong with that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use separate `ALTER COLUMN` clauses for the type, null behavior, and default value:

```
ALTER TABLE my_table
ALTER COLUMN my_field TYPE numeric(12,4),
ALTER COLUMN my_field SET DEFAULT 0,
ALTER COLUMN my_field SET NOT NULL;
```